# Starling Framework - loading external swf / sharing context

Tags: actionscript-3, external, stage3d, starling-framework

I have project which includes main menu and several levels (pages), all based on Starling Framework. I want to separate pages from the main application to keep logic, views and effects in external swfs.

Example: App Menu where user may choose different game (puzzle, pingpong, chess ...), pages ("Options", "About"). Those components has nothing to do with each other so I dont want to make one giant project. 
What is the best practise to separate those pages and load them to main app?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider two options. Both might require you to create a main sprite class for each component that can be attached to root in the main application.

1. Embed all the different SWFs in a main application and instantiate the classes inside the component SWF within main application.

   - [Embedding with Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata.html?PID=5232140)
   - [Embedding Assets in AS3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html)
2. Export the different components as SWCs and import them into your main project so that you can instantiate them in your main application.

   - [Using SWC to build large projects](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/combine-swfs-with-swcs.html?PID=5232140)